# Angular 13 (Tour of heroes) - Prerender and refreshing view problem

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I downloaded "Tour of heroes" from Angular website (https://angular.io/tutorial). I added Angular Universal to my project:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

Then I added to package.json:

```
"prerender": "ng run angular.io-example:prerender --routes /detail/11"
```

Static pages has been generated correctly. Unfortunately, when I go to `/detail/11` page I saw a refreshing of the view layer ([live example](https://brnit.bialystok.pl/test/detail/11/) (network - slow 3g) and [unexpected behaviour video example](https://watch.screencastify.com/v/W3MI2kHv0Nqpy6YTHbSa))

I would like to avoid refreshing the page because it looks like a bug. Cumulative Layout Shift parameter doesn't like shifts. Thank you in advance for your help.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular.io-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run angular.io-example:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/angular.io-example/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run angular.io-example:server",
    "prerender": "ng run angular.io-example:prerender --routes /detail/11",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^13.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.11.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^13.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "~0.8.3",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's seems ok in live example with slow 3g network!

Comment: For a while the page is blank for hero details. For complex elements and fetching data from external api CLF will be hight.